# Generate jenkins jobs for all github repos

Tags: github, jenkins

I would like to set up some automation inside Jenkins that periodically polls the list of repos in our github organization and automatically sets up a jenkins job for each of that Git repos based on a job template.

What would be a possible solution to achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jenkins Pipeline is nowadays the way to go.

It defines pipelines using a `Jenkinsfile`, which you can check into your repos.

Which the best practice is a file like this

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                echo 'Building..'
            }
        }
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                echo 'Testing..'
            }
        }
        stage('Deploy') {
            steps {
                echo 'Deploying....'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As described [in the documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/).

Comment: Thanks for answering my old question. Indeed, I've been using pipeline quite a bit (very successfully). Gave also couple of [talks](https://slideshare.net/stephenking) about that, so definite recommend.

Comment: hope it's okay that I changed your posting a bit.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [Jenkins Job DSL plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Job+DSL+Plugin)

which is a build step in jobs to create and modify other jobs

From the Wiki:

> The job-dsl-plugin allows the programmatic creation of projects using
>   a DSL. Pushing job creation into a script allows you to automate and
>   standardize your Jenkins installation, unlike anything possible
>   before.

An example would be:

```groovy
def organization = 'jenkinsci'
repoApi = new URL("https://api.github.com/orgs/${organization}/repos")
repos = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(repoApi.newReader())
repos.each {
  def repoName = it.name
  job {
    name "${organization}-${repoName}".replaceAll('/','-')
    scm {
      git("git://github.com/${organization}/${repoName}.git", "master")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks like a good starting point, as there is also a [Maintain Jenkins jobs for each branch of a project on Github](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/Real-World-Examples) example that should be easy to adopt.

Comment: Using my excellent Groovy skills, I was able to adopt the example from the docs and added it here ^^

Comment: How can I add git credentials for GitHub API URL ?

Comment: I don't have access to a working Jenkins anymore, At a guess, you could probably leverage the credentials plugin, or the Git Plugin. You should probably ask a new question